# PHP авторизация и сессий

Tags: php, сессия

Практикуюсь с пхп и столкнулся с небольшой проблемой.
У меня есть файлы: index.php (главная страница) и auth.php(форма)

Мне нужно получить переменные готовые с данными из файла auth.php в index.php Пробовал сделать так

```
include 'auth.php';
```

Но у меня поверх главной страницы вставляется html код формы. Как мне получить данные из файла auth.php в index.php ?? Я пробовал через session_start(); и просто в сессий хранить значения

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $username;
?>
```

Но мне кажется это неправильно :( или можно так делать?

Comment: Можно и так делать

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.forms.php уже читали документацию?

Answer (score 0):

В файле auth.php, в форме, укажите куда слать данные, например отправить в index.php. Разметка auth.php должна примерно быть такой

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="login">
    <input type="text" name="password">
</form>
```

А в файле index.php Вы можете обращаться к переменным так: $_POST['login'] и $_POST['password']

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте получить значение так:

```
<?php  echo ($_SESSION['name']->name); ?>
```